# Use OnBeforeSerialisation of derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im tyring to make a custom property drawer for a property with nested properties.

The nested properties are derived from a base class and needs to be drawn differently.

To get around this when serialising I'm trying to make an array of `string` values with relevant data and let each derived class populate the list in its own way.

But now I realise that when `OnBeforeSerialisation` is called its always and only called on the base class. Is there a way to make it use the overrided version in the derived class?

```
[Serializable]
public class MF : ITEngineUpdatable
{
    [SerializeField] float baseValue;
    [SerializeField] List<MFModifier> modifiers;

    [SerializeField] float currentValue;

    public float Value { get => currentValue; }

    void ITEngineUpdatable.Update()
    {
        var actualValue = baseValue;

        foreach (var modifier in modifiers)
        {
            actualValue += modifier.Value;
        }

        currentValue = actualValue;
    }

    public MF(float baseValue)
    {
        modifiers = new List<MFModifier>() { new MFTModifier(6, 7) };
        this.baseValue = baseValue;
        TEngine.Engine.InitialiseMe(this);
    }
    public void AddModifier(MFModifier modifier)
    {
        modifiers.Add(modifier);
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class MFModifier : MFModifierBase
{

    [SerializeField] protected float value;
    [SerializeField] protected List<string> serialisationData;
    public MFModifier(float value)
    {
        serialisationData = new List<string>();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override float Value { get { return value; } }

    public override void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
     
    }

    public override void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        serialisationData.Clear();
        serialisationData.Add("MFModifier");
        serialisationData.Add(Value.ToString());
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class MFTModifier : MFModifier
{
   [SerializeField] timier timier;
    public void Run()
    {
        timier.Run();

    }

    public MFTModifier(float baseValue, float duration) : base(baseValue)
    {
        timier = new timier(duration);
        timier.Run();
    }

    new public float Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (timier.isActive)
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0f;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        serialisationData.Clear();
        serialisationData.Add("MFTModifier");
        serialisationData.Add(Value.ToString());
        serialisationData.Add(timier.Remains.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are serializing a `List<MFModifier>` => for the serializer these are only `MFModifier` no `MFTModifier`

From [Script Seialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html):

> **No support for polymorphism**
>
> If you have a public `Animal[]` animals and you put in an instance of a `Dog`, a `Cat` and a `Giraffe`, after serialization, you have three instances of `Animal`.
>
> One way to deal with this limitation is to realize that it only applies to custom classes, which get serialized inline. References to other `UnityEngine.Objects` get serialized as actual references, and for those, polymorphism does actually work. You would make a `ScriptableObject` derived class or another `MonoBehaviour` derived class, and reference that. The downside of this is that you need to store that `Monobehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` somewhere, and that you cannot serialize it inline efficiently.
>
> The reason for these limitations is that one of the core foundations of the serialization system is that the layout of the datastream for an object is known ahead of time; it depends on the types of the fields of the class, rather than what happens to be stored inside the fields.

Comment: I understand this as there just is no way to use inheritance on custom classes that is a monob or scriptableo. That's OK I can do without it will not be as flexible but it's good to know that I should design the system this way. Thanks.